# Why does generator yield value after loop

Tags: python, generator

I've been learning how send method and yield assignment work in generator and met a problem:

```py
def gen():
    for i in range(5):
        x = yield i
        print(x)
s = gen()
print(next(s))
print(s.send(15))
```

output:

```
0 #after print(next(s))
15
1
```

so it prints 15 and 1 after `print(s.send(15))`. It broke my understanding of yield, because I don't understand why it yields 1 after printing x. I'm wondering if someone knows the answer.

Comment: `0` comes from `print(next(s))`, since it gets its value from the `yield` in the first iteration of the loop.  `15` comes from `print(x)` inside the loop, because `15` was passed in via `send` and then assigned to `x`.  `1` comes from `print(s.send(15))`, because `send` returns the value from the next `yield` in the coroutine, which in this case comes from the second iteration of the loop.

Comment: @0x5453 but there is still little question: generator stops right after yield 0 without assigning it to x and then after `send(15)` it replaces `yield 0`with `15` and assigns it to x and then continues running until next yield?

Comment: That is correct.  The function execution essentially "pauses" *right* in the middle of the assignment statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `s.send(15)` the generator resumes running. The value of `yield` is the argument to `s.send()`, so it does `x = 15` and the generator prints that. Then the `for` loop repeats with `i = 1`, and it does `yield i`.

The value of `s.send()` is the next value that's yielded, so `print(s.send(15))` prints that `1`.

Comment: but there is still little question: generator stops right after yield 0 without assigning it to x and then after `send(15)` it replaces `yield 0` with `15` and assigns it to `x` and then continues running until next yield?

Comment: `yield` suspends the generator and sends the value to the caller. When the caller calls `send()`, the generator resumes and assigns the sent value to `x`.

Comment: I think you need to read a tutorial on Python generators to get a good grasp on how this all works.

Comment: I have, but this expanded protocol with assigning yield expression wasn't explained with such details

Comment: It's not a frequently used feature. Most generators just return data, they don't take back more input.